# "Use cinto também no banco detrás"

Tags: gramática

Vindo para o trabalho hoje passei por uma placa com os dizeres acima, que me parecem estar errados por não usarem 'de trás'.

Sendo uma placa oficial do Governo, gostaria de saber se está de fato errada.

[image: pics or it didn't happened]

[Fonte](https://www.google.com.br/maps/@-23.2659087,-46.8606795,3a,75y,303.34h,74.81t/data=!3m6!1e1!3m4!1s976IjVXNPUXovLiLJkzYjQ!2e0!7i13312!8i6656)

Comment: Não conhecia a palavra detrás...

Comment: @JorgeB. também desconheço, sem bem que desconheço bastante da parte escrita.

Comment: @Centaurus não querendo também parecer rude, mas você discorda que o nosso site possa ser uma fonte de referencia?

Comment: Carla uma duvida, quando diz *do Governo* você na verdade quer dizer do acordo Ortográfico? Sobre o resto da pergunta, acho totalmente valiada e parece pertencer a uma "série" de palavras que se assemelham +1

Comment: @Guilherme: É mesmo engano do Governo. O acordo ortográfico não mexeu no *de trás* e *detrás* . A resposta do Artefacto aplica-se igualmente às grafias anterior e posterior ao acordo.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento   Mesmo ainda estando em beta, perguntas cujas respostas podem ser facilmente encontradas em dicionários comuns são consideradas "off-topic" no Stack Exchange.  Gostaria de ouvir os moderadores do site  Jorge B, tchrist and Earthlin

Comment: @Centaurus primeiro discordo de ser algo que moderador define, quem faz isto é a "comunidade" e a "necessidade". Segundo a questão se for para a discordância de ambos lados deve se seguir no META, esta pergunta eu já fiz lá pelo mesmo motivo, segue link [Question without prior research](http://meta.portuguese.stackexchange.com/q/60/8), entenda como uma critica construtiva ;)

Comment: @Centaurus o mais apropriado é abrir uma discussão no meta para discutir o assunto, além disso podes colocar a questão para fechar com o motivo "off-topic because..." e ver o que a comunidade acha. Posso dar a minha opinião se abrires a questão no meta, para não estar a debater aqui nos comentários.

Comment: @Centaurus Eu não acho que a pergunta seja trivial de todo, antes pelo contrário.

Comment: Vixi, saí por uns diazinhos e o negócio já tá pegando fogo...mas enfim: sim, a palavra está no dicionário e de fato não tinha reparado na sutileza apontada pelo Artefacto de que 'detrás' é apenas um advérbio, não há indicação de ser adjetivo [não que a indicação da classe gramatical seja suficiente pra toda pessoa sacar se o uso está correto ou não]; pois é, a placa foi colocada pelo Governo, ia colocar uma foto do Google Maps, mas a placa é muito recente...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Sim, de facto devia ser «banco de trás». Esse é até exatamente o exemplo do [Aulete](http://www.aulete.com.br/tr%C3%A1s):

> **De trás**
>   1 Que se situa atrás; traseiro: *Foi sentar-se no banco de trás.*

Portanto *de trás* é um adjunto adnominal, que funciona como o adjetivo *traseiro*.

Apesar de o Aulete não o mencionar (mas veja-se o [Priberam](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/de%20tr%C3%A1s)), *de trás* também pode ser usado para iniciar um sintagma preposicional que funciona como adjunto ou argumento de um verbo. Como argumento, o verbo tem de admitir sintagmas começados por *de*, como *sair* ou *vir*:

> Esse problema já vem *de trás*.
>   Ele saiu *de trás* das cortinas.
>   Compreendo isso *de trás* para a frente.

Já *detrás* é um advérbio, substituível por *atrás*. Vejam-se os exemplos do [Aulete](http://www.aulete.com.br/detr%C3%A1s):

> 1. Na parte posterior ou oposta à parte principal: *A casa da prefeitura é aquela, a que está detrás abriga uma secretaria*
> 2. Depois, em seguida: *Ele sempre vem detrás dos outros*

Também se pode combinar com preposições e e formar as locuções prepositivas *detrás de* e *por detrás de*.

Há casos em que *de trás* e *detrás* são ambos possíveis, mas  o significado difere. Repare-se:

> O dono do café contrapõe, ***de trás*/*detrás*** do balcão, que «as empresas que existem em Évora são a universidade e a Siemens».

Com *de trás* estamos a indicar o **lugar de onde** o dono do café fez a contraposição, enquanto com *detrás* indicamos o **lugar onde** o dono do café a faz (semelhante a *atrás do balcão*).

Comment: Excelente resposta e apontamento do erro, também me pareceu um erro, mas a sua resposta foi o que me fez entender que realmente é e o porque. +1

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento A tua resposta eliminada tem um singificado de _de trás_ que não cobri. Adicionei-o também.

Comment: eu pensei em editar a sua resposta para fazer isto, mas não sei como é a cultura aqui, se o pessoal se sente ofendido ou algo, apesar de ser algo permitido nem todo mundo gosta infelizmente :/ - Todavia fico feliz pela sua edição.

Comment: Muito bom, sua resposta tirou a pulga de trás da minha orelha.